# Upper case problem in fancy head

Tags: fancyhdr, glossaries-extra

I have a large document with severals packages loaded. In this, I have `fancyhdr` package and the command `\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}` to put chapter title in the head of the page, with non upper case letters. Since I am writing in portuguese, the head was looking like this:

[image]

Everything was working fine, but then I added the `glossaries-extra` package, and now all head pages changed to this situation:

[image]

This problem with the "Í" happens only in the head; foot is ok, no problem.

Any clue about that? Thanks in advance! Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
\fancyfoot[L]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{{\scriptsize Some text 1. Word Capítulo.}}{{\scriptsize Capítulo. Word Capítulo. Conclusão.}}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
} 

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={some symbol}]{A}{\ensuremath{A}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sumário}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={Lista de Símbolos}]

\chapter{Este é o início}
\label{inicio1}
Problem in the next page. Capítulo word.

\newpage
Words.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of code producing the issue?

Comment: @egreg I just added. Look above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the issue by adding, before `\begin{document}`

```latex
\addto\extrasportuguese{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Cap\'itulo}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00ED}{\'i}
```

The problem is that `glossaries-extra` does `\let\MakeUppercase\MakeTextUppercase` and this has consequences on how command expansion works. So, instead of leaving `\protect\MakeUppercase` in the left mark, LaTeX finds `\protect\MakeTextUppercase` and the `\nouppercase` macro doesn't take care of this.

Probably `fancyhdr` should be updated so the macro `\nouppercase` also nullifies `\MakeTextUppercase`. Here's an appropriate patch.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
\fancyfoot[L]{%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}
    {{\scriptsize Some text 1. Word Capítulo.}}
    {{\scriptsize Capítulo. Word Capítulo. Conclusão.}}%
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
} 

%\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={some symbol}]{A}{\ensuremath{A}}

%% fix the wrong uppercasing
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\f@nch@reset
 {\let\uppercase}
 {%
  \let\MakeTextUppercase\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname MakeTextUppercase \endcsname\relax
  \let\uppercase
 }
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sumário}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={Lista de Símbolos}]

\chapter{Este é o início}
\label{inicio1}
Problem in the next page. Capítulo word.

\newpage
Words.

\end{document}
```